# how can I return the child variable in an extended base method with Java oop

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
public class Buildings {
public int getLevel(){
    return level;
}
}
 public class MainBuilding extends Buildings{
public static final int cost = 200;
public static int  level = 1;
}
MainBuilding main = new MainBuilding();
main.getLevel();
```

I want have several building with diffrent instantsvaribles like level and cost but they should have the same method getLevel() that just returns the level. I can't find how I can do these with java...

Comment: why you put them as static ? why you redeclared in child class?

Answer (score 0):

*Either* move the `level` variable (which should probably be an instance variable, rather than a static variable) to `Buildings` *or* make `getLevel()` abstract so that each subclass has to implement it separately (whether that's by returning a variable, or just always returning a constant, or whatever - that's an implementation detail).

Answer (score 0):

I believe their are some error in your example code. these are

1. you have not define level variable in Buildings class.
2. static method can use only static variable. (in MainBuilding variable level is static. but Building method is non-static)

here you can solve these two problem simply and execute then getlevel() function will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Buildings {
    private int level;

    public int getLevel(){
        return level;
    }

    public int setLevel(l){
        level = l;
    }
}

public class MainBuilding extends Buildings{
    public static final int cost = 200;

    public MainBuilding() {
        setLevel(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 Calling an overridable method in constructor is an open door for potential undesired behaviour